# Reference named expression in SQLite expression

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to do something like this in sqlite3, where "...somelongexpression..." is a placeholder for my actual expression logic:

```
SELECT ...somelongexpression... AS subexpr, subexpr * 2 AS twicesubexpr FROM sometable;
```

But, I'm getting "Error: no such column: subexpr".

Can I not reference one named column expression in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in SQL in this form.

You would have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT subexpr,
       subexpr * 2 AS twicesubexpr
FROM (SELECT ...somelongexpression ... AS subexpr
      FROM sometable);
```